# INSERT INTO not sending data to database

Tags: php, mysql

This is the code to insert into MySQL.
However, for some reason, it is not sending data to the database.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","esferinf_fpessoa","mypassword","esferinf_factura");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query("INSERT INTO Entregas (dia, cliente, toalhetes, higienico, bidons)
VALUES ('$dia', '$cliente','$toalhetes', '$higienico', '$bidons')");
```

I don't understand what's going on, what's missing to me?

Comment: And you also want to read about [Prepared Statements](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: try replacing "mysqli_query" with "echo" and see what that gives you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mainly missing the link in your query

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO Entregas (dia, cliente, toalhetes, higienico, bidons) VALUES ('$dia', '$cliente','$toalhetes', '$higienico', '$bidons')");
```

Also, if this is user input, make sure you validate and sanitize your variables.

It would be even better if you started using prepared statements

Comment: @andrew what is the case then? he does need to surround the fieldname with backticks and he is missing the link

Comment: the backticks are not necessary unless the column names consist of reserved words, and the connection is the 2nd parameter not the first

Comment: php.net/mysqli_query @andrew it's actually the first parameter

Comment: @andrew - the connection link is the first parameter in [`mysql_query()`](http://cz1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), not in [`mysqli_query()`](http://cz1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). Also, it is required in `mysqli_query()` and optional in `mysql_query()`.

Comment: @ChosenWann You're absolutely right, my apologies, I was not reading my intellisense correctly, if you make some edit, I can upvote

Answer (score 0):

@andrew has found your problem, but there are a couple other issues:

- You're not properly escaping your values. This will cause bugs if somebody inserts special characters in your input, and could allow a hacker to steal data from your server.
- You should be using PDO, since that is the modern API for accessing MySQL.

Here's how todo an insert statement properly, if you don't want to use PDO then you need to learn about SQL injection.

```
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=esferinf_factura', 'esferinf_fpessoa', 'fer1pes4');

$statement = $con->prepare('
  insert into Entregas set
  dia = :dia,
  cliente = :cliente,
  toalhetes = :toalhetes,
  higienico = :higienico,
  bidons = :bidons
');

$statement->execute(array(
  'dia' => $dia,
  'cliente' => $cliente,
  'toalhetes' => $toalhetes,
  'higienico' => $higienico,
  'bidons' => $bidons
));
```

Comment: @user3450641 if you have a different problem you should ask it as a different question.

Comment: I apreciate all your help, but I think there is something else, as no one had work.
Anyway, thank you all, people.

Comment: Hello Abhi. Your code did work. I cleaned some lines of my code, and now, it works. I really need to learn more about PDO anf mysqli. Thank you very, very much. Fernando

Comment: You should mark my answer as accepted then. :-) PDO replaces mysqli, you only need to learn one, not both. PDO is the better one to use, it's newer and many flaws in mysqli have been solved in PDO.

Comment: Done. Once more, Thank you. Fernando